# Which language to use

Tags: search

I have zero experience with coding and I am wanting to begin learning. I want to create a project as I learn and need help in deciding which language is appropriate for what I am thinking about creating.

The application I have in mind is to search a pre-existing website that lists first and last names throughout multiple pages and run each of the names through another website utilizing its search funtions to see if any matches are found. If any matches are found I would like to be notified. This is just something I thought of when thinking about what I want my first project to be to make my daily job easier and less tedious. The process would not be something that is constantly running but one that I can run whenever I choose to see if any results are found with the current names. Any insight would be great on what programming language would be best for something like this.

Comment: You can try [Small Basic](https://smallbasic-publicwebsite.azurewebsites.net/)

Answer (score 0):

This is of course an opinionated answer but I'd recommend python, because its:
- very easy to learn
- easy to setup
- has awesome web scraping library